# using min and max in group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want below output in oracle sql.

I have data in table as below :

```
id    start_date      end_date      assignment number

1     2.02.2014       15.02.2014    10
2     25.02.2014      30.02.2014    20
3     26.03.2014      04.05.2014    30
4     06.06.2014      31.12.4712    10
```

I need output using group by

```
assignment_number   start_date          end_date

10                  02.02.2014          15.02.2014
10                  06.06.2014          31.12.4712
20                  25.02.2014          30.02.2014
30                  26.03.2014          04.05.2014
```

I tried using min(start_date) and max(end_date) for assignment 10 ia was getting output as

```
assignment_number   start_date          end_date
10                  02.02.2014          31.12.4712
```

But I want as :-

```
assignment_number   start_date          end_date
10                  02.02.2014          15.02.2014
10                  06.06.2014          31.12.4712
```

Please help

Comment: As it currently stands, your requirement doesn't really make sense. Either you want the min() and max() for each assignment (in which case your results are correct), or you want each line from the table (in which case you don't need `GROUP BY` at all). Please provide more information about the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd have to calculate the min and max separately, then union them. Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
 assignment_number
 , start_date
 , end_date
 FROM 
      (SELECT
                assignment_number
                , start_date
                , end_date
                FROM TABLE
                GROUP BY assignment_number
                HAVING MIN(start_date)

           UNION

           SELECT
                assignment_number
                , start_date
                , end_date
                FROM TABLE
                GROUP BY assignment_number
                HAVING MAX(end_date)
      )
 ORDER BY 
      1 ASC
      , 2 ASC
      , 3 ASC
```

;

Answer (score 1):

[**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e562/6)

```
select id, to_char(start_date,'dd.mm.yyyy') start_date, to_char(end_date,'dd.mm.yyyy') end_date,ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER from sof1 s
where not exists 
                (select 1 from sof1 s2 
                 where s2.assignment_number=s.assignment_number 
                 and s2.start_date<s.start_date
                )
or not exists 
                (select 1 from sof1 s2 
                 where s2.assignment_number=s.assignment_number 
                 and s2.end_date>s.end_date
                )
order by ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER
```

With analytic function:

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e562)

```
select id, to_char(start_date,'dd.mm.yyyy') start_date, to_char(end_date,'dd.mm.yyyy') end_date,ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER from 

(select s.*
 , min (start_date) over (partition by ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER) sd
 , max (end_date) over (partition by ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER) ed
 from sof1 s
)
where start_date=sd or end_date=ed
order by ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER, start_date
```